Averaging two rasters preserving the non-overlapping areas with python gdal
I have two rasters with the same projection that partially overlap. How to to calculate the average of the overlapping area preserving the values from one of the rasters in non overlapping areas using python and gdal or rasterio? 

If they are not too big to fit in RAM/memory*, you could use rasterio.merge.merge with sum and count operators and calculate mean from sum/count.
Example
I have three partially overlapping test datasets. input1.tif contains only 1's as pixel values, input2.tif contains 2's and input3.tif contains 3's.
If I mosaic them, I would expect to get the input values (i.e 1,2 & 3) where they don't overlap, 1.5 where input1.tif and input2.tif overlap and so on for other average values and NoData where no valid pixels overlap.
gdalinfo -stats input1.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input1.tif
Size is 2596, 1678
Origin = (-1505188.094100000103936,-3592640.986399999819696)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=1.000, Mean=1.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100


Code
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.merge import merge
import numpy as np

inputs = ["input1.tif", "input2.tif", "input3.tif"]

inputs = [rio.open(i, masked=True) for i in inputs]
profile = inputs[0].profile.copy()
nodata = np.finfo("float32").min  # use min float32 value for nodata 

merged_count, merged_transform = merge(inputs, method="count")
merged_sum, merged_transform = merge(inputs, method="sum")

profile.update(
    driver="GTIFF",
    dtype="float32",  # inputs are integer and the mean can be non-int and I don't want to truncate
    transform=merged_transform,
    count=merged_count.shape[0],
    height=merged_count.shape[1],
    width=merged_count.shape[2],
    nodata=nodata
)
mask = merged_count == 0
merged_mean = merged_sum/merged_count
merged_mean[mask] = nodata
with rio.open("output.tif", "w", **profile) as output:
    output.write(merged_mean)

Output

* If they are too big to fit in memory, an upcoming version of rasterio (2.0?) will include a mem_limit argument to process in chunks.

Thank you, I get this error message "ValueError: Unknown method count, must be one of ['first', 'last', 'min', 'max'] or callable"

@ilFonta Update your rasterio version. The count and sum methods were added in v. 1.3.0 back in 2022.

Thank you, now it works but it produces strange average values

Can you define strange average values? Can you edit your question and include the output of the command line gdalinfo your-raster.tif?

I solved with this
import subprocess
f1 = "/media/giacomo/VERDE/Brix/temp_GRD_afrisar_dlr_CH1-0_BIOMASS_ANN_BRIX2.tiff"
f2 = "/media/giacomo/VERDE/Brix/temp_GRD_afrisar_dlr_CH2-2_BIOMASS_ANN_BRIX2.tiff"
fout= "/home/giacomo/Immagini/out.tiff"


command = f'gdal_calc.py -A {f1} -B {f2} --outfile={fout} --calc="(A+B)/ 2" --extent=union'

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

